# open two different socket input stream

Tags: java

I have a server and a client.  The server receives two command strings: `add` or `remove`. If server receives `add`, it adds the object it receives from the socket to a local list.  Is it acceptable to open two different streams consecutively to receive two different objects?

Example:

```
/* To read the command */
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
/* To read the object */
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not necessary. `String` is `Serializable`. You could do something like this:

```
String s = (String) ois.readObject();
Object o = ois.readObject();
if("add".equals(s)){
    list.add(o);
} else if ("remove".equals(s)){
    list.remove(o);
}
```

Just make sure you use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` to send both your command and object.